# What is the code for a number sign in sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint

I've created a link in Sharepoint using the Content Editor Web Part.  My link uses html to open up an email with the fields to, cc, subject, and body filled out.  However, in the cc section I need a number sign (#) for a mailbox.  When I use the html code & #35;(minus the space) my entire code crumbles.  Everything starting at the "&" disappears.

However, just for kicks I tried & pound;(minus the space) and the code works for a european pound sign.  Not sure what else to try.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `%23`.  This worked for me from a Sharepoint (2003) Content Editor webpart.

```
<a href="mailto:someone@example.com?cc=%23212-555-1234
&subject=Hello again, %23007">
Send Mail</a>
```

The email generated by this link looks something like like this:

To: someone@example.com
cc: #212-555-1234
Subject: Hello again, #007

Comment: Bingo, I knew it had something to do with not having the first part of the sign, I forgot it was change to % ...

Comment: @Robin ~ Don't forget to mark an answer with the green checkmark. Look under the up/down voters

Answer (score 0):

You said you've tried `&#35;` but what about `&35;`?

Note: I have no clue if that makes a difference at all, but I would try it... Also, I imagine this is some sort of quirky thing that you'll never see anywhere but sharepoint, but idk...

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and it just shows as "&35;".  At least that does not drop all my code following it though.  It is definitely only a sharepoint issue.  I have been reading forum after forum trying to find some sort of answer. :-/